# Complexity of 2 for loops inside 1 for loop

Tags: for-loop, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory, space-complexity

```
for(int i=1;i<=n*n;i++)
{
   for(int j=1;j<=i/2;j++)
   {
         s=s+i+j;
   }
    k=1;
   while(k<j)
   {
        s=s+k;
        k=k*2;
   }
}
```

So I know that the complexity is O(n^4), but I don't quite get it how to get there. I know that the first loop has **n*n** so it's more. However, 2 for's inside another usually mean O(n^2), so I just have (n^2)^2, due to the first **n * n**? Or the two fors inside mean an `n` each? The second for runs only for even values of i and the thrid one the same, maybe that counts. Please help. I'm confused because I remember some example that 2 fors inside another for is O(n^2*logn). If anyone cares to explain about that, I'll be thankful.

Comment: is k-`while` nested in j-`for`?

Comment: no no, like I didn't but brackets because if there aren't any, it will take the first next thing only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your first guess is pretty much right. The outer for (i) will go for n^2 iterations. The inside for (j) will cost at most n^2 as well in single iteration. `while` can be in this case ignored (you can use n^2 as very rough upper bound for it). So you have n^2 x n^2 and that's your n^4.

Comment: So even without the while, I would still have n^4?

Comment: It's dubious because k=k*2 means usually that it's a logn complexitiy

Comment: Yes, I believe so because it's much smaller than complexity of the j-for.

Comment: Log n is much smaller than n^2 so when you are using O notation you can skip it when you are interested in a rough estimation.

Comment: So you mean that when i=n*n, then j will be max n^2/2 , but 1/2 is not taken in consideration so it will remain n^4, ok that makes sense

Comment: and n^2 x (0.5n^2 + logn) <= n^2 x (0.5n^2 + n^2) = n^2 x 1.5 n^2 = 1.5 n^4

Comment: one more thing, if we have a for(i) that goes i*2, and inside it , a normal for(j;j++) , will it be logn *n ?

Comment: Your last comment isn't clear for me, can't answer, sorry ;)

Comment: ```for(int i=1;i<=n;i=i*2)
    {
       for(int j=1;j<=n;j++)
       {
```

Comment: this will be O(log(n)* n) ? they are nested

Comment: Thank you again, you helped me a lot